# What is wrong with my WP_Query Arguments?

Tags: wp-query, categories, single, parameter

In my single.php file I am using a nested WP_Query to show more posts, at the bottom of the page. My code for the query and nested loop are as follows:

```
<?php 

    $ep_args = array(
        'post_type'       =>    'post',
        'category_not_in' =>    93,
        'orderby'         =>    'rand',
        'posts_per_page'  =>    4,
        'offset'          =>    1,
    );

    $ep_query = new WP_Query( $ep_args );

    while ($ep_query->have_posts()) : $ep_query->the_post();

        if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;

    get_template_part( 'content', 'postthumb' ); 

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I have tried using both `'category_name'` (with the desired category's slug) and `'category_not_in'` (with the undesired category's ID), and in both cases I am getting posts from the undesired category. Furthermore, I'm finding that using `'orderby' => 'rand'` will only result in 3 posts instead of 4, if I do not set the offset to 1.

How can I get my query to result in 4 posts from one specific category, and no other categories?

Comment: Are these undesired categories sub-categories? You shouldn't hardcode term IDs like that. You should also wrap your loop in an `if ( $ep_query->have_posts() )` to prevent reseting the post data if it was never set

Comment: They are not sub-categories.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one-

`'category__not_in' => array( 93, 94, 95 ),`

instead of-

`'category_not_in' =>    93,`

Note: The term is **category__not_in**, not **category_not_in**. Use 2 underscores after **category**.

**Edit:** You are using-

`'offset' => 1`

That forces to show posts from 2nd one (skips the first post). So, it's showing one post less! If you use `'offset' => 3`, then it will start from 4th post.
Hope you understand.

Comment: This gets rid of the post from the undesired category, however I now only have 3 posts showing, instead of 4.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Have you verified there are actually 4 posts to show? With the offset field, you'll need there to be 5 posts for 4 to show

Comment: I have 7 posts in the desired category (9 posts total), more than enough. I should be able to offset by 1 and still get 4 posts from my query, not 3. Update: I have edited my query to remove the offset (I initially thought it was necessary since I was using `if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;`  to keep the current post from showing up in my query, but now it doesn't seem to be necessary). I now have simply `'post_type' = 'post'`, `'category_name' = 'episodes'`, `'orderby' = 'rand'`, and `'posts_per_page' = 4`, and now sometimes I get 4 posts, but a lot of times I only get 3 posts.